# Change state value in context file from child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, react-props, use-state

Trying to understand context api, and I understand props are passed down. I am trying to change state of my Context file's value to another number like 50.

Created Context File

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const PointsContext = createContext();

export const PointsProvider = (props) => {
  const [points, setPoints] = useState(0);**<--WANT TO CHANGE THIS**

  return <PointsContext.Provider value={points}>{props.children}</PointsContext.Provider>;
};
```

Wrapped Everything In Provider in App.js

```
import {PointsProvider } from "./PointsContext";

<PointsProvider>
     <ChildComponent>
</PointsProvider>
```

The "ChildComponent" is Provided Context

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { PointsContext } from "../PointsContext";

const value = useContext(PointsContext);

return(
    <Button title="ChangeNumber" onPress={() => Change value to 50 }/>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, instead of importing

```
const value = useContext(PointsContext);
```

import this, which gives access to the setState in the context file. As long as you import this on to any screen you will have access to that useState to change stuff.

```
const [points, setPoints] = useContext(PointsContext);
```

the rest might go something like this!

```
<Button title="ChangeNumber" onPress={() => setPoints(50)}/>
<Text>{points}</Text>
```

This tutorial helped alot thanks devEd, he is one of my favs!
[DevEd Youtube React State](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=35lXWvCuM8o&t=1326s)